# ajax Laravel 8 jquery-3.4.1.js:9837 DELETE http://agenda.devetapia.cl/citas/delete/1 500 (Internal Server Error)

Tags: ajax, laravel-8, delete, error500

Estoy haciendo una aplicación con fullcalendar.io y necesito eliminar una cita en la tabla.
Estoy usando Laravel 8. Estoy ocupando ajax para comunicarme con el servidor pero me muestra error 500 uando invoco el metodo delete

Mi controlador:

```
public function destroy(Cita $cita_id)
{
    $cita = Cita::find($cita_id);
    
    $cita->delete();
    
    return back()->with('succes', 'Cita eliminada correctamente');

}
```

Mi ruta:

```
Route::delete('/citas/delete/{cita}', [App\Http\Controllers\CitaController::class, 'destroy'])->name('citas.delete');
```

La consola me entrega esto:

```
jquery-3.4.1.js:9837 DELETE http://agenda.devetapia.cl/citas/delete/1 500 (Internal Server Error)
send @ jquery-3.4.1.js:9837
ajax @ jquery-3.4.1.js:9434
(anonymous) @ agenda.js:207
dispatch @ jquery-3.4.1.js:5237
elemData.handle @ jquery-3.4.1.js:5044
```

Mi javascript

```
                $('#btnEliminar').click(function(){
              
              if (!confirm("Está seguro de eliminar la cita?")) {
         
              }
              else{ // eliminar

                let urldelete = "http://agenda.devetapia.cl/citas/delete/"+id;
                $.ajaxSetup({
                  headers: {
                          'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
                      }
                  });
            
                $.ajax({
                  type: "DELETE",
                  url : urldelete,
               
                  success: function (data) {
                      console.log("exito")
                  },
                  error: function (data) {
                      console.log('Error:', data);
                  }
                  
                });
              
              }
```

No he podido determinar que estoy haciendo mal.

Comment: Revisa los logs de laravel y/o apache/nginx. Agrega el error a tu publicación para tener más información.

Comment: El log de Laravel me arroja: `Method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::delete does not exist. {"userId":7,"exception":"[object] (BadMethodCallException(code: 0): Method Illuminate\\Datab       ase\\Eloquent\\Collection::delete does not exist. at /home/ubuntu/environment/agenda/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Macroable/Traits/Macroable.php:113)
325275 [stacktrace]`

Comment: Tampoco me funciona `dd($cita);` en el controlador.

Comment: Ahora el log cambió a: `local.ERROR: Call to undefined function App\Http\Controllers\delete() {"userId":7,"exception":"[object] (Error(code: 0): Call to undefined function App\\Http\\Controllers\\dele       te() at /home/ubuntu/environment/agenda/app/Http/Controllers/CitaController.php:258)`

Comment: La respuesta me la dieron por acá (https://stackoverflow.com/a/70827705/17938122)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El error 500 como indica ya es de parte del servidor, por lo que no debe de haber nada malo en tu javascript.

Te recomiendo utilices un try y catch para manejar el error y asi al menos obtener contexto de lo que salio mal.

```
public function destroy(Cita $cita_id)
{
   try {
      $cita = Cita::find($cita_id);
      $cita->delete();
   } catch (Exception $ex) {
        return back()->withError($ex->getMessage())->withInput();
   }
   return back()->with('succes', 'Cita eliminada correctamente');
}
```

Espero te ayude a buscar la solucion.

Comment: Mostrar los mensajes de error que no son parte de una validación controlada puede dejar problemas de seguridad a futuro. Lo mejor es usar el [sistema de logs](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/logging) que trae por defecto laravel y el estándar [RFC 5424](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc5424)

Comment: La respuesta me la dieron por acá https://stackoverflow.com/a/70827705/17938122